# UnityContainerExtensions.cs not found

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, unity-container

After updating some NuGet packages, it turned out that some things in my website got broken by new code. I updated to the new Unity inversion control 5.0.0, etc. So after a while of hunting around and trying to fix it, I was able to get it to finally build and launch the site. However, the Unity IOC was broken because I kepts getting the "Error in Application '~/', controller must have a parameterless constructor". I saw that my couple of Unity files (UnityConfig.cs and UnityMvcActivator.cs) were gone, so I replaced them with ones I had in the backup folder.
Well, now it launches a loading site, but in VS it now says "UnityContainerExtensions.cs not found". I see that it looks all over for this file, around 'C:\ Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC...' and then it goes looking through 'c:\projects\unity]Abstractions\src\Utility...' - a folder that I can't even see.

This is in VS2015, doing a web application with Framework 4.6.

What can I do to just make it work again, as when I first had it so many months ago?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I was able to fix my Unity problem by rolling back on some of the packages. I'm the kind of person who likes to have no notifications, so I clicked Update All, and apparently the updates weren't necessarily compatible with my project here. To get it working again I has to bring back:

1. Unity.Abstractions = 2.0.0
2. Unity = 4.0.1
3. Unity.AspNet.WebApi = 4.0.1
4. Unity.Mvc = 4.0.1

Now to great relief, all works just as it did before!
However, I do wish I knew why the breakages happen and also why these packages are listed as updates when they are not going to work with my project.
Till the future, my system is going to have to consist of a Post-It "Do not update these xxxx packages, they will break stuff". And I wish to gain an understanding of what is the reason behind such Unity mess.

[image]